# Send json data flutter post

Tags: flutter

I want to send in this form in `http.post`
but I can't manage to encode my data in my body.

I have an error:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception:
> Converting object to **
> **> an encodable object failed: Instance of 'MappedListIterable<User, Set>'**
> **> E/flutter ( 7489): #0      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:688:7)**

Comment: a simple jsonEncode(mydata) should do. else share your model and your post method

Comment: var e = data.map((e) => 
     [{details['n']=e.libelle,details['n']=e.quantite,details['n']=e.prix}]);               the format of the data I want to send                                                                                                          var donee = {'fournisseur': fournisseur, 'produit': e};      print(jsonDecode(donee));

Comment: then jsonEncode(donee) should do the trick, or you can encode your map var e

Comment: the error I get when I do this

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Converting object to 
an encodable object failed: Instance of 'MappedListIterable<User, Set<String>>'

Comment: Share your code

Comment: ///on save forms                                                                                         Future<void> onSave() async {
    if (users.length > 0) {  var allValid = true;
      users.forEach((form) => allValid = allValid && form.isValid());
      if (allValid) {  var data = users.map((it) => it.user).toList();
           var e = data.map((e) =>  {details['n']=e.libelle,details['n']=e.quantite,details['n']=e.prix});  
        var donee = {'fournisseur': fournisseur, 'produit': e};
           var res = await Network().Ajout(
           donee, '/auth/facture', ); } } }

Comment: Ajout(data, apiUrl) async {
    var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl;
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token1 = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString("token").toString());
    return await http.post(
        Uri.parse(fullUrl),
        body:  jsonDecode(data),
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token1'
        }
    );
  }

Comment: Try adding `.toList()` to `var e = data.map((e) => {details['n']=e.libelle,details['n']=e.quantite,details['n']=e.prix})`. And also see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).